# How to change marker's opacity between 0.5 and 1 when clicked

Tags: leaflet

I need my marker to change opacity every time I clicked it, the default opacity of my marker is 1 and when I click it, I want it to changes its opacity to 0.5 and change it back to 1 when clicked again. How can I achieve this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [.setOpacity(0.5)](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#marker-setopacity)

```
marker.on('click',function(e){
   var marker = e.target;
   if(marker.options.opacity === 1){
       marker.setOpacity(0.5);
   } else {
       marker.setOpacity(1);
   }
});
```

Comment: sorry im new and i dont see any button that does that. edit, i got its thanks again